# php get free space /dev/sda linux

Tags: php, linux, diskspace

I have stage code

```
$totalSpace =  74.5GB ;

$freespacespace = disk_free_space('/dev/sda')/1024/1024;

$usedSpace = $totalSpace - $freespacespace;
```

==>

total Space:  74.5GB ;

free spacespace:  1.46 GB ;

used Space: 73.04GB ;

While in command

i have

```
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0  74.5G  0 disk
|-sda1                         8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
|-sda2                         8:2    0     1K  0 part
`-sda5                         8:5    0  74.3G  0 part
  |-ubuntu--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0  71.3G  0 lvm  /
  `-ubuntu--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0     3G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
dev_php@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   71G  2.8G   64G   5% /
udev                         1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs                        301M  348K  300M   1% /run
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                    236M   32M  192M  14% /boot
```

How to get free space?

free space in one of the partitions on that drive disk /dev/sda

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: thanks anigel. quesion of me.
How to get free space? disk /dev/sda

Comment: When you say free space /dev/sda what do you mean? currently unpartitioned space or free space in one of the partitions on that drive?

Comment: free space in one of the partitions on that drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the free space on a partition using `disk_free_space("/dev/sda1")`

Just note that there are multiple partitions on this drive so any attempt to do disk size - space in partition will not give you an accurate view of how much space is used in that partition as the partition itself is not the full size of the disk.

Comment: What does not make sense? disk_free_space("/dev/sda1") gives you free space on a partition which is what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly. You can use below command to get free space.

```
df -h | awk '{print  $3}'
```